# Scrapy Text after <div>

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to crawl the following HTML code using Scrapy:

```
<tbody id="pageData11">
<tr>
<td>
<div style="border-left:3px solid #1A8CFF  !important; float: left; padding-right: 5px;">&nbsp;</div>
2018-May-29 Tuesday
</td>
```

Comment: required output is 2018-May-29 Tuesday

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, the answer to your question is `response.xpath('/html/body/tbody/tr/td/div/following::text()').extract_first().strip()`, but, in this case, it's also the text in the `td`. Thus you can also do something like `"".join(i.strip() for i in response.css('td::text').extract())`.

Answer (score 0):

Just considering your given example in question.

```
response.css('td::text').extract())
```